# ActiveMerchant - Can I integrate a Merchant ID Number with Authorize.net?

Tags: e-commerce, authorize.net, activemerchant

I'm building an e-commerce website from scratch in Ruby on Rails. I currently have PayPal integrated into the site, but the client wants to go with a cheaper solution (that takes less cut than PayPal.) I don't have a website for them, they don't have integration docs. All I got was a Merchant Identification Number (MID). The guy from the payment company said that my client would be able to use this Merchant Identification Number when the shopping cart site asks for it.

The payment guy thinks that my client is using a pre-packaged solution like Volusion or Magneto.

Can I use the Authorize.net payment gateway with just a merchant identification number? It looks like from this page, http://activemerchant.rubyforge.org/classes/ActiveMerchant/Billing/AuthorizeNetGateway.html#method-M000393, that I need an Authorize.Net API Login ID and an Authorize.Net Transaction Key.

What information am I missing from the payment guy?

He said that we could use VeriSign or Authorize.net... but VeriSign was acquired by PayPal, wasn't it?

Comment: I spoke with the guy directly on the phone. He is going to figure out what login ID and transaction key I need. What is the merchant identification number used for by payment gateways? Is it a universal identification number or does each payment gateway supply their own?

Comment: Worst-case scenario, you need to generate a new gateway in ActiveMerchant. Depends on who handles the payments in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The merchant ID is required, along with other details, to register for an Authorize.Net account. Once you have that account they will provide you with the API loginand transaction key. Then you. Can integrate it into active merchant and accept payments.

Comment: Oh interesting! Is there only one API ID and Transaction Key per merchant ID?

Comment: Yes. One merchant ID per Authorize.Net account. Each account gets one api id and key.